# How to return a subset of the DataFrame’s columns based on the column dtypes in Spark Scala

Tags: python, pandas, scala, apache-spark

I need to divide my dataset into different subsets based on the data types.

In Pandas we can do it by df.select_dtypes, I want to implement this in Spark Scala. Can anyone please help.

For example, below is my dataset:
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcx3n.png)

I want to divide the dataset based on the datatypes into Float and String.

My final output should be something like this, with two different dataframes with similar data types in them.
[Subset of Dataframe with only floating values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5VUz.png)

[Subset of Dataframe with only String values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RwNm.png)

****Note: 1) We already have a Pandas package in PySpark, but I want to implement in Spark Scala.
2) If you can also help in how to seperate the columns with different DATE datatype will be really helpful****

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Below is my code, where I'm trying to divide String, Numbers and dates into different dataframes based on their datatypes:

```
+---+------+----------+---+----------+------+-------+
|Sno|  Name|       DOB|age|     jdate|Salary|Country|
+---+------+----------+---+----------+------+-------+
|  1|Charan|1995-03-13| 23|2017-08-23| 34873|     CA|
|  2| Arjun|1996-03-23| 33|2016-08-23| 36777|    USA|
|  3|   Ram|1994-06-13| 19|2012-12-12| 24873|     UK|
|  4|  Ravi|1997-04-13| 30|2019-08-23| 97853|     CA|
|  5| Indra|1999-03-13| 23|2000-08-23| 64773|    USA|
|  6| Rajni|1993-03-13| 23|2017-09-23| 67873|     UK|
+---+------+----------+---+----------+------+-------+
val data = sc.textFile("test.txt")
val header = data.first()
val datawh = data.filter(x => x != header)
case class Data(Sno:Integer, Name:String, DOB:String, age:Integer, jdate:String, Salary:Int, Country:String )
val idata = datawh.map(rec => { var d = rec.split('|');
(d(0).toInt,d(1).toString, d(2).toString, d(3).toInt, d(4).toString,d(5).toInt, d(6).toString)
})
var dataDF = idata.map(x => Data(x._1, x._2, x._3, x._4, x._5, x._6, x._7)).toDF()
```

What code should be written below this to seperate the column data into seperate datasets or dataframes based on datatypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val fieldsByDataType: Map[DataType, Array[Column]] = ds.schema.fields.groupBy(filed => filed.dataType)
      .mapValues(fields => fields.map(field => col(field.name)))

for ((dataType, columns) <- fieldsByDataType) {
  println(s"Dataset for $dataType")
  ds.select(columns:_*).show()
}
```

Example:

```
val ds = Seq(
      ("dep1", "M", 1200, 34),
      ("dep1", "M", 800, 30),
      ("dep1", "F", 200, 21),
      ("dep2", "M", 1000, 21),
      ("dep2", "M", 1200, 22),
      ("dep2", "F", 500, 24),
      ("dep2", "M", 600, 44)
    ).toDF("department", "gender", "salary", "age")

Dataset for StringType
+----------+------+
|department|gender|
+----------+------+
|      dep1|     M|
|      dep1|     M|
|      dep1|     F|
|      dep2|     M|
|      dep2|     M|
|      dep2|     F|
|      dep2|     M|
+----------+------+

Dataset for IntegerType
+------+---+
|salary|age|
+------+---+
|  1200| 34|
|   800| 30|
|   200| 21|
|  1000| 21|
|  1200| 22|
|   500| 24|
|   600| 44|
+------+---+
```

Comment: Gelerion, Thanks for the help. I'm bit new to this.. I'm getting below errors     ds: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [department: string, gender: string, salary: int, age: int]
<console>:192: error: not found: type DataType
       val fieldsByDataType: Map[DataType, Array[Column]] = ds.schema.fields.groupBy(field => fieldd.dataType)
                                 ^
<console>:192: error: not found: type Column
       val fieldsByDataType: Map[DataType, Array[Column]] = ds.schema.fields.groupBy(field => fieldd.dataType)

Comment: Does importing these two resolves the issue? import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Comment: Yes it Solved the issue. Can you please help me in storing them to or saving them into different data frames or datasets. Can it be done for Date data types too..

Comment: `ds.select()` returns you a new `Dataframe`. Feel free to do whatever you want with it.
e.g. `set.add(ds.select())`, or `fieldsByDataType.mapValues(columns => ds.select(columns:_*))`. So that you have a map with dataset splitted by a data type.
Not sure if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want to save the results with similar datatypes into different Data frames. So, I can reduce my dataset and analyse my results only on particular dataset.

Answer (score 2):

There is this function `dtypes` which can help, like:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//df is the DataFrame containing the input data
df.dtypes.groupBy(_._2).map { case (k, v) =>
  (k, df.select(v.map { x => col(x._1) }: _*))
} // Returns Map[String, DataFrame] where key -> DataType and value -> subset Dataset
```

Comment: Pritish, can you please look into the code below and make the suggestions,           val data = sc.textFile("test.txt")

data.take(10)

val header = data.first()

val datawh = data.filter(x => x != header)

case class Data(Sno:Integer, Name:String, DOB:String, age:Integer, jdate:String, Salary:Int, Country:String )

val idata = datawh.map(rec => { var d = rec.split('|');
(d(0).toInt,d(1).toString, d(2).toString, d(3).toInt, d(4).toString,d(5).toInt, d(6).toString)
})


var dataDF = idata.map(x => Data(x._1, x._2, x._3, x._4, x._5, x._6, x._7)).toDF()